# how to cancel last request when click a btn in react js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to cancel an **Axios request** when clicking the **button** in react js

I read Axios documentation but don't find it

Comment: [Is this helps ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71137878/how-to-integrate-abortcontroller-with-axios-and-react)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

```
const controller = new AbortController();
    
axios.get('/foo/bar', {
    signal: controller.signal
}).then(function(response) {
   //...
});

// cancel the request
controller.abort()
```

Comment: it does not work :(