# AbortController with Axios and React is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, abortcontroller

Although this question has been asked many times, it still doesn't work in my case. I followed the answer from @Drew Reese at [How to integrate AbortController with Axios and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71137878/how-to-integrate-abortcontroller-with-axios-and-react) but the abort() does not seem to work. My code looks like this.

I first create an exported `Axios` (latest version) instance.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
   baseURL: API,
   headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
   },
});


axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
   config.formSerializer = { indexes: null };
   return config;
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Inside my react component I do this.

```
import axios from '../mycomponents';
const abortControllerRef = useRef(new AbortController());

...
...
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (mydata) => {
...
...
      try {
         axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
         const res = await axios({
            method: 'post'
            url,
            data: mydata,
            onUploadProgress : handleProgress,
            signal: abortControllerRef.current.signal,
         });         
      } catch (err) {
         if (err.name === 'CanceledError') { 
            console.error('Operation canceled');
            // reset controller
            abortControllerRef.current = new AbortController();
         else 
            console.error(err);         
         
      }
  

}

.....
.....
const cancelUpload = () => {
      const controller = abortControllerRef.current;
      controller.abort();
};
```

the `cancelUpload` is called from a button callback but it never aborts a list of uploading files (multiple files were selected).

**EDIT after @AkeelAhmedQureshi suggestion**

*After @AkeelAhmedQureshi suggestion I fixed the `signal` typo error. Now, I can catch the error and report the cancelation upload, BUT Axios continues the posting and finally, after some seconds, the server receives most of the payload (ie 2 out of 5 files and the rest of the data) as normal. The server completes the transaction even with some of the files originally selected.  Where am I wrong here?*

Here is what my browser reports.

[image]

Comment: signal: abortControllerRef.current.signal, write the signal instead of singal.

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi Can you explain what exactly should I write?

Comment: you have written singal in react component, you should write signal

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi Yes, it's unbelievable I didn't see that. After 10h of developing I can not see anything right now :-) Thank you !!! Please add your answer below

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi let me ask you one thing if you like. While I catch the abortion error and report the appropriate error to the user, internally, the axios post request continues. Finally, after some seconds it sends the data to the server's side. Why is that? abortController is supposed to break this request, am I right?

Comment: When you use the AbortController to abort a request, it triggers the AbortError in the associated promise, and this error is caught in your catch block. However, the fact that the error is caught doesn't necessarily mean that the request is immediately stopped on the server side.

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi What to do in this case? It always continues....

Comment: If you want to prevent the server from processing the request after it has been aborted on the client side, you may need to implement some mechanism on the server to recognize and handle aborted requests. This might involve checking for the existence of a header or parameter that indicates the request has been aborted.

Comment: @AkeelAhmedQureshi Thanks !!! Is there any working example to recommend?