# Cancelling HTTP Post request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

In react how to cancel a post request, I use react `query` and `fetch()`. I wanted to cancel a post request while pending when another request is made. So, the scenario is whenever a user touches some button it fetches a result from an API endpoint, and currently, whenever  a user presses a button again while the first request is pending, it doesn't cancel it. It fetches the first one and then the second get through.

I tried to use Abort Controller but it isn't working for me.

Comment: `AbortController` is the solution for this, if you show us some code we can help debug why it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate AbortController with Axios and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71137878/how-to-integrate-abortcontroller-with-axios-and-react)